# C: scanf() storing memory address integer instead of integer value

Tags: c, for-loop, memory, scanf

I'm writing a C program to take the marks of five subjects, calculate the average mark and associate a grade.

While scanning in subjects, I noticed unexpected behavior; the score integer variable that is scanned to is storing a memory address of an integer, instead of the value of the integer value.

When scanning in, for example, 95, from stdin, and then immediately printing it, my program prints a value of 32859.

I am not sure what the cause of this error is, and presume it may be to do with the fact that I'm using scanf() within a for loop. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix my problem. Any tips help!

```
#define SUBJECTS 5

#include <stdio.h>

char * find_grade(float);

int main()
{
    int subject_score_sum;
    // Scan in the subjects
    for (int count = 0; count < SUBJECTS; count++)
    {
        int score;
        scanf("%d", &score);
        printf("%d\n", score);
        subject_score_sum += score;
        printf("%d\n", subject_score_sum);

    }



    float average_score = ((float)subject_score_sum / (float)SUBJECTS);

    

    printf("Average = %.2f\n%s\n", average_score, find_grade(average_score));


    return 0;
}

char * find_grade(float average_score)
{
    if(average_score >= 90)
    {
        return "Grade A";
    }
    else if(average_score >= 80)
    {
        return "Grade B";
    }
    else if(average_score >= 70)
    {
        return "Grade C";
    }
    else if(average_score >= 60)
    {
        return "Grade D";
    }
    else if(average_score >= 40)
    {
        return "Grade E";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Grade F";
    }
}
```

Comment: A large values does not mean it is an address.

Comment: "When scanning in, for example, 95, from stdin, and then immediately printing it, my program prints a value of 32859." Cannot reproduce. When I run your program it prints the entered value and the value of the non-initialised sum variable (+ the sum of entered vaues).

Comment: _"When scanning in, for example, 95, from stdin, and then immediately printing it, my program prints a value of 32859."_ I don't believe you.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the variable `subject_score_sum`. 
Because of this, its value is undefined and `printf("%d\n", subject_score_sum);` just prints something. 
Even worse: This undefined behavior means your compiler could compile this program into whatever it wants (even into ransomware encrypting all your files!).

Also, make sure to check the return value of `scanf`. 
`scanf` returns the number of sucessfully read formatters (in your case, this should be `1`).

Comment: I initialize the variable ```subject_score_sum``` in line 9 as an integer.

Comment: Akiyuu, please quote the line in which you initialise it instead of only defining it. I do not see it. Line 9 is by my count `int subject_score_sum;`, i.e. not initialising.

Comment: you `declare` the variabel in line 9. However, this does not initialize it.
`C` doesn't assign default values to variables (like e.g., `Java`). Thus, you must explicitly initialize it with `0` (`int subject_score_sum = 0;`)

Comment: This helped my understanding, so thank you.

Comment: Could you see my answer down below and see why declaring a float, but not initialising it, has different behaviour?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well, no compiler does it, but according to the C standard, they could.

Comment: @Akiyuu That's the beauty of undefined behavior: It is undefined :D
Jokes aside, the value is located on the stack. For some reason, the stack layout is different when you use a float, or the compiler chooses to initialize it with 0 for some reason.
Likely, it just so happens that there is a zero at the correct location on the stack. But this may vary from compiler to compiler or even from machine to machine or even from run to run. Don't rely on undefined behavior doing what you want!

Comment: @Akiyuu your answer is wrong. `subject_score_sum` is not initialized. The fix is initialising it to 0 like e.g. `int subject_score_sum = 0;`

Comment: @Akiyuu _"I initialize the variable subject_score_sum in line 9 as an integer."_, no you don't, you declare it as an `int`. Declaring and initializing ar two different things. Local variables are not initialized to zero in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought that integers initialized to zero upon declaration. Thank-you, yes, this was my problem.

Comment: yes, this is undefined behavior. The variable `subject_score_sum` could have been declared with the  `register` keyword, as it never has its address taken and is used when it is not initialized (6.3.2.1 paragraph 2). 
(I am not 100% sure about this because of the += which has `subject_score_sum` implicitly at both sides, either way, using uninitialized variables are always a bad idea)